# What does this piece of code do in React JS build file?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I'm currently working on Reactjs. And using create-react-app build my app.

I'm just curious about what does this piece of code do in the build index.html file.

```
<script>!function (l) { function e(e) { for (var r, t, n = e[0], o = e[1], u = e[2], f = 0, i = []; f < n.length; f++)t = n[f], p[t] && i.push(p[t][0]), p[t] = 0; for (r in o) Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(o, r) && (l[r] = o[r]); for (s && s(e); i.length;)i.shift()(); return c.push.apply(c, u || []), a() } function a() { for (var e, r = 0; r < c.length; r++) { for (var t = c[r], n = !0, o = 1; o < t.length; o++) { var u = t[o]; 0 !== p[u] && (n = !1) } n && (c.splice(r--, 1), e = f(f.s = t[0])) } return e } var t = {}, p = { 1: 0 }, c = []; function f(e) { if (t[e]) return t[e].exports; var r = t[e] = { i: e, l: !1, exports: {} }; return l[e].call(r.exports, r, r.exports, f), r.l = !0, r.exports } f.m = l, f.c = t, f.d = function (e, r, t) { f.o(e, r) || Object.defineProperty(e, r, { enumerable: !0, get: t }) }, f.r = function (e) { "undefined" != typeof Symbol && Symbol.toStringTag && Object.defineProperty(e, Symbol.toStringTag, { value: "Module" }), Object.defineProperty(e, "__esModule", { value: !0 }) }, f.t = function (r, e) { if (1 & e && (r = f(r)), 8 & e) return r; if (4 & e && "object" == typeof r && r && r.__esModule) return r; var t = Object.create(null); if (f.r(t), Object.defineProperty(t, "default", { enumerable: !0, value: r }), 2 & e && "string" != typeof r) for (var n in r) f.d(t, n, function (e) { return r[e] }.bind(null, n)); return t }, f.n = function (e) { var r = e && e.__esModule ? function () { return e.default } : function () { return e }; return f.d(r, "a", r), r }, f.o = function (e, r) { return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e, r) }, f.p = "./"; var r = window.webpackJsonp = window.webpackJsonp || [], n = r.push.bind(r); r.push = e, r = r.slice(); for (var o = 0; o < r.length; o++)e(r[o]); var s = n; a() }([])</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is minified code (not meant to be human readable and as short as javascript allows) generated by webpack at build time.

Specifically, it looks like helper code for module import/export translation for an environment that doesn't support modules.